# Finding eigenvectors with square root eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 &-1 &2\\2 &-2 &4\\0 &1 &1\end{bmatrix}$$

Its eigenvalues are $0$, $\sqrt{5}$ and $-\sqrt{5}$
(These are checked in MATLAB to be correct). I have found its eigenvectors for $0$, and also don't seem to have a problem in similar situations when the eigenvalues are not "root". But when I have root, and are not allowed to turn into descimal-numbers, I have no clue how to proceed.

Does anyone know how to find eigenvectors when the values are $\sqrt{x}$? I'd be happy to watch a youtube video, or an example of how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

The method to find an eigenvector is the same, regardless of what the eigenvalue is.  The only difference between different eigenvalues is the appearance of the computation involved.  For example, you will need to add, multiply, divide by real numbers like $(1-\sqrt{5})$.

More details:

To compute an eigenvector, you need to solve the system $Av=\lambda v$.  For $\lambda=\sqrt{5}$, you need to solve the system $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & -1 & 2\\2 & -2 & 4\\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right]\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\sqrt{5} x\\ \sqrt{5} y \\ \sqrt{5} z\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, which becomes the system:

$(1-\sqrt{5})x -y +2z=0\\ 2+(-2-\sqrt{5})y + 4z=0\\ 0x+y+(1-\sqrt{5})z=0$

Comment: Had to edit away

Answer (score 2):

If you want results to compare against, you should get for $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 &-1 &2\\2 &-2 &4\\0 &1 &1\end{bmatrix}$, the following characteristic polynomial:

$$5 \lambda - \lambda^3 = 0$$

This CP yields the following eigenvectors and eigenvalues:

$\displaystyle \lambda_1 = -\sqrt{5}, v_1 = \left(\frac{1}{2} (-1-\sqrt{5}), -1-\sqrt{5}, 1\right)$

$\displaystyle \lambda_2 = \sqrt{5}, v_2 = \left(\frac{1}{2} (-1+\sqrt{5}), -1+\sqrt{5}, 1\right)$

$\lambda_3 = 0, v_3 = (-3, -1, 1)$

**Update**

To find the eigenvectors, for **each** eigenvalue, we solve:

$$|A -\lambda_i I|v_i = 0$$

For $\lambda_3 = 0$, we have:

$$|A -\lambda_3 I|v_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \\2 & -2 & 4\\0 & 1 &1\end{bmatrix}v_3 = 0$$

The RREF is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 3 \\0 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}v_3 = 0$$

Here, we have:

$a + 3 c = 0$, and

$ b + c = 0 \rightarrow b = -c, \text{so pick}~~ c = 1 \rightarrow b = -1$

So, $a = -3c \rightarrow a = -3$

Thus for $\lambda_3 = 0$, we have $v_3 = (-3, -1, 1)$

For $\lambda_2 = \sqrt{5}$, we have:

$$|A -\lambda_2 I|v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1-\sqrt{5} & -1 & 2 \\2 & -2-\sqrt{5} & 4\\0 & 1 &1-\sqrt{5}\end{bmatrix}v_2 = 0$$

The RREF is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{5} \\0 & 1 & 1-\sqrt{5}\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}v_2 = 0$$

So, we have:

$a + \frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{5})c = 0$, and

$b + (1-\sqrt{5})c = 0$

So, we can choose: $c = 1 \rightarrow b = (-1+\sqrt{5})$

This leads to: $a = \frac{1}{2}(-1 + \sqrt{5})$

So, for $\lambda_2 = \sqrt{5}$, we get $v_2 = \left(\frac{1}{2} (-1+\sqrt{5}), -1+\sqrt{5}, 1\right)$.

Can you repeat this process for the last eigenvalue? If not give a yell and I will add details.

Comment: How are you able to deduce the eigenvectors like that from the CP?

I reached the CP and also had no problems deducing the different eigenvalues, but did you do more algebra to reach the vectors, or is there some trick I'm not seeing? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Student: please see my updates for eigenvector calculations for the details on two of the eigenvalues. If you cannot do the third, please give a yell. Regards

Comment: I found it myself, using Ross Millikans method. I found that alot easier than making RREF with roots in my matrix. Not steady enough in lin. alg. yet I guess

Comment: Nice Amzoti. +1

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you my friend! Hope all is well with you as it seems you have been quite busy these days! Regards

Comment: I agree with Babak! ;-) +1

Comment: @Amzoti: Yes I am busy with semigroups these days, to propose a nice paper in that area. So, you see me so weak and reluctant to answer. :-)

Comment: @BabakS.: Well, I hope your efforts are fruitful and that your paper is stupendous! Great luck my friend!

Answer (score 1):

Calling your matrix $A$, the eigenvalue $\lambda$ and the eigenvector $y$, you use the fact that $(A-\lambda I)y=0$  So $$\begin{bmatrix}1-\sqrt 5 &-1 &2\\2 &-2-\sqrt 5 &4\\0 &1 &1-\sqrt 5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$ and read off three equations in three unknowns, just like you did for $\lambda=0$  The equations will be dependent, so there will be a one-parameter family. I'll use the first and third for convenience.
$$(1-\sqrt 5)y_1-y_2+2y_3=0\\y_2+(1-\sqrt 5)y_3=0\\y_2=(\sqrt 5-1)y_3\\(1-\sqrt 5)y_1+(3-\sqrt 5)y_3=0\\y_1=\frac {3-\sqrt 5}{\sqrt 5-1}y_3=\frac {(3-\sqrt 5)(\sqrt 5+1)}{(\sqrt 5-1)(\sqrt 5+1)}y_3=\frac {2\sqrt 5-2}4y_3$$ So your eigenvector is any multiple of $$\begin{bmatrix}\frac {2\sqrt 5-2}4\\\sqrt 5-1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So its no problem giving the eigenvector in that form?

Comment: This makes alot of sence. Thank you very much

Comment: @Student:  No.  One can feed it to a calculator and get decimal approximations, but this is the exact answer.  Depending on the use, it may be important  to save the $\sqrt 5$'s so you know they really subtract to zero.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Congratulations Ross. I read something about you in Meta. +!